# Merging local-only branches with a remote branch

Tags: git

I'm kinda new to git and I don't understand something. Let me explain.

I have 2 branches that are tracked on remote. There is a common code between them and I want to isolate this code in a third local-only branch (ie not pushing the changes to the origin). After that I want to merge this local branch with the other 2 branches.

Now the question is - when I push from my 2 branches to the origin, is the master branch going to be aware of this third (local-only) branch that I made? And is this going to make the merging between the 2 branches easier?

Comment: Branches aren't "aware" of each other.  Remember that Git is just a big graph of commits, and branches are just pointers to specific elements of that graph.  When you push a branch, what you're really doing is pushing all of the historical commits (including the corresponding graph structure).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth With the exception of remote tracking branches, anyway - there is some sense of "awareness" there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it sounds like you have two branches, something like:

```
       A-B-C   br1
      /
-*-*-M         master
      \
       U-V-W   br2
```

And you want to extract a new branch for some common changes - let's called that `shared`:

```
       A-B-C   br1
      /
-*-*-M-----S   shared
      \
       U-V-W   br2
```

And then merge that branch into your other existing branches?

```
       A-B-C-D br1
      /     /
-*-*-M-----S   shared
      \     \
       U-V-W-X br2
```

Assuming I have understood your description correctly:

> when I push from my 2 branches to the origin, is the master branch going to be aware of this third (local-only) branch that I made?

No, `master` will stay at commit `M` until you do something to it (`commit`, `merge`, `reset`, etc).

> And is this going to make the merging between the 2 branches easier?

Probably It really depends on the nature of commit `S` and its relationship to the other changes from which you extracted your shared changes, but generally it's a good idea to recognize such shared changes and finish them in isolation before merging them back into the branches that depend on the common code.

Comment: If S then is the "isolate this code in a third local-only branch" then its commits will get pushed along with br1 and br2, so although the ref name "shared" won't, the commits from M..S will.

Comment: Correct. Generally my preference for this sort of thing would be to identify the need for a `shared` branch, `cherry-pick` the appropriate commits out of `br1` and `br2`, and `rebase` those branches onto `shared` to eliminate the changes been introduced into multiple places.

Comment: Thanks for answering! This helps me a lot. So if the only common thing between br1 and br2 is the changes in the shared branch than my merge is going to be easy (no conflicts)?

Comment: Yep, should be easy and conflict-free!